# Calculation of date & time and echo in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to echo some text if the difference between datetime from MySQL and the current datetime is more than sixty seconds.

But my code is showing every time.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.php';

$reg = new USER();

$stmt = $reg->runQuery("SELECT * FROM validation WHERE vid=2"); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
$usrmail = $row['vdate'];

$login_session_durations = 60;

if(((time() - $usrmail) > $login_session_durations)) { 
    echo "Ok";
}
?>
```

Date & Time set in MySQL is `2017-09-17 06:53:39.000000`

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you need an actual date type variable, because what's returned from the database is probably just a string.. Edit: What I mean is, something like `strtotime($usrmail)`. Take a look: [https://3v4l.org/bifcA](https://3v4l.org/bifcA)

Comment: If I go with `strtotime($usrmail)` it does not show if the difference is greater than duration.

Comment: Check here : https://eval.in/863155

Answer (score 0):

`time()` gives you the output in Unix format like `1505622974`so to compare we need both the times variable in the same format.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'class.php';

    $reg = new USER();

    $stmt = $reg->runQuery("SELECT * FROM validation WHERE vid=2"); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
    $usrmail = $row['vdate']; //The format for vdate: 2017-09-17 06:53:39.000000

    $login_session_durations = 60; //In Seconds

    if(((time() - strtotime($usrmail)) > $login_session_durations)) { 
        echo "Ok";
    }
?>
```